# Botframework Facebook Channel Gives 403

Tags: botframework

My bot's Facebook Channel doesn't work. My credentials is right. Server always gives 403 Forbidden.

[Here is request picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXYLh.png)

Comment: Have you tried `api.botframework.com`? (Instead of `facebook.botframework.com`.)

Comment: I tried it instead of skype.botframework.com . Always gives this:
`{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "message": "Resource not found"
}`

Comment: Look please is URL right?:
`https://api.botframework.com/v3/conversations/2scBs5kz58rLDQEC/activities`

Comment: Looks correct. Have you created a conversation before? (`POST` to `https://api.botframework.com/v3/conversations`)

Comment: I'm sended message to bot's skype. And received request from webhook. I took conversation id from that request:
`...`
`"conversation": {
    "isGroup": false,
    "id": "29:16TaxVHUvlzyFDJpdJJ4NnadhxtLnqBgoNx8stAOmkJ8"
  },`
`...`

Comment: Well anyway, 403 suggests there's some problem with the authentication. How do you do that? Did you get the token as described here? docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication/#authentication-calls-from-the-bot-to-the-bot-connector-service

Comment: I tried this: `https://api.botframework.com/v3/conversations` with POST. Gives: `{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "message": "Resource not found"
}`

Comment: I'm using Microsoft OAuth 2.0 token (`Bearer .......`). It's working on skype and webchat. And If i use wrong token it gives 401 Unauthorized. But if token is right, gives 403 Forbidden. I'm not understand this. Why it fails with 403?

Comment: I'm getting token from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: Sounds correct. This (unresolved) issue might be relevant: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/697.

Comment: Oh, thank you for letting me know. I'll follow this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to use the conversationId from Skype on Facebook?

Comment: If you mean like `https://facebook.botframework.com/v3/conversations/29:XXXXXXXXXXX/activities`, yes. It gives 403 Forbidden, too.

Comment: But skype and webchat channel working.

Comment: But i am using like this: `https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations/29:XXXXXXXXXXX/activities`. On facebook channel, `https://facebook.botframework.com/v3/conversations/1234578156574989-270578663310581/activities` so conversationId is `1234578156574989-270578663310581`

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a similar problem.